# "#Error" in Place of all Calculations Made with Custom Assembly in SSMS

Tags: reporting-services, ssms

Using reporting services 2005.  I have a set of reports that use a custom assembly for some basic calculations.  It has been deployed several times in the past successfully.

I am trying to install the reports and assembly on a new instance of SQL Server, and the repors work fine as far as pulling back and displaying data.  The only problem is that all the fields and labels that require the use of the custom assembly display the word "#error" instead of the correct label or field.

It is difficult to google, since the "#error" results in a search for "error", which does not give me the results I am looking for.  However, the few articles I did find seem to point to a policy config file problem or a security problem.  I have checked the config file against a working implementation, and have opened up the security on the directory in every way I can think of, all to no avail.

Any other ideas on how to even begin to troubleshoot this problem?